# Posting form with XmlHttpRequest/ajax alters payload

Tags: javascript, forms, asp.net-core, xmlhttprequest

I want to `Post` a form using `Ajax/XMLHttpRequest` to a `ASP NET Core Controller`.
If i simply `Post` the form it gets the data right in the `Controller` but when using `XMLHttpRequest` the fields of my `model` get defaulted:

I have included my  in my code below 2 forms:
-one form that simply `Posts` to the `url` specified in the `action` attribute, and the other that calls a `method` and `Post`-s with `XMLHttpRequest`.

**HTML+JS**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        window.submit = function () {
            var form = document.getElementById("delegate-form");
            var data = new FormData(form);
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            var content=form.getAttribute('Content-Type');
            var method=form.getAttribute('method');
            var action=form.getAttribute('action');
            xhr.open(method,action);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',content);
            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    resolve(xhr.response);
                }
                else if (xhr.status != 200) {
                    reject("Failed to submit form with status" + xhr.status);
                }
            }
            xhr.send(data);
        };


    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="Form-without-ajax">
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost:8300/api/bulk">
            <input type="text" name="Name" value="aa" />
            <input type="text" name="ID" value="13"/>
            <input type="file">
            <br>
            <input style="align-content: flex-end" type="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div id="Form-with-ajax">
        <form method="POST" id="delegate-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost:8300/api/bulk">
            <input type="text" name="Name" value="ab" />
            <input type="text" name="ID"  value="33"/>
            <input type="file">
            <br>

        </form>
        <button onclick="submit()">Submit with delegate</button>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**Model**

```
 [Serializable]
    public class Data {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

**.NET Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/api/bulk")]
    public async Task TestBulkAsync(Data data) {
        //data has Name=null and id=0 when using the XMLHttpRequest
    }
```

**P.S** I am using `multipart/form-data` because i want to attach some files too besides that model.And i need a handler like in my case `submit` because i need to perform additional logic before submitting the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',content);
> ```

Normally, if you pass a FormData object to XMLHttpRequest, it will generate the Content-Type header (which will be a multipart request with a specific boundary attribute) from the FormData object.

Here, you are overriding the Content-Type with one you are determining manually … and you are omitting the boundary attribute. The server then doesn't know where the boundaries are and everything breaks.

Don't override the Content-Type.

Comment: Thank you very much.I was not aware of that.

Comment: I know it should be a separate question but do you have any idea why it does not see my `file` in the `controller` `this.Request.Form.Files` ?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian — inputs without name attributes cannot be successful controls

Comment: But why would they need `names` since the `.net` framework already places the files in a separate  file `collection` ? They are not part of my json .

Comment: Because form data is a collection of name=value pairs. The browser can't send them without a name.

Comment: If .NET dumps all file inputs into a separate collection and discards the names … how are you supposed to distinguish between multiple file inputs once the data gets to the server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188985/discussion-between-bercovici-adrian-and-quentin).